# Can anyone explain how to use the onProgress in inertia useForm.js submit

Tags: javascript, callback, inertiajs

I am trying to use the inertia useForm.js submit function and I found that the onProgress is execute but console.log didn't print out anything.

```
Inertia.post('/generateFile', form, {

    onProgress: () => {
        console.log("onProgress");           
        openGeneratingFileDialog();   
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
        console.log("onSuccess");  
        openSuccessDialog();                   
    },
    onError: () => {
        console.log("onError");       
        opneFailDialog();
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the progress event is only fired when uploading files.

So if you want to use the `onProgress`, you have to ensure you are uploading a file, otherwise will be useless.

Docs [here](https://inertiajs.com/events#:%7E:text=is%20not%20cancelable.-,Progress,-The%20progress%20event) (Progress section).